# Translation of "A car powered by nuclear fuel.": zero article or partitive article

Tags: traduction, articles

(J'ai rencontré le terme "zéro article" dans le livre: A student grammar of French by M. Offord, p. 204.)

Comment peut-on traduire la phrase ci-après ?

*A Car Powered by Nuclear Fuel.*

> Une voiture alimentée par combustible nucléaire

ou

> Une voiture alimentée par du combustible nucléaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is possible but it's not really what we would use.

Here are more idiomatic suggestions:

> Une voiture à moteur nucléaire

or

> Une voiture à propulsion nucléaire